# Regex - Match all numbers from a specific character until any non digit

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get 4654052 from the text below. Numbers starts from `--` until `?`. `?` 
 can be any non digit character.

```
here-is-some-string--4654052?day=2018-10-17
```

I have [tried](https://regex101.com/r/cS0oU9/7) `\D.*|\D+` but it want the text to start with a digit.

Comment: What regex engine/programming language are you using?

Comment: @PoulBak Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the text to start with a digit, you can use a **capture group**. Try this expression:

```
--(\d+)\D
```

`\d+` represents "one or more" digits, and `\D` represents a non-digit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this in `sed`:

```
 $ echo "here-is-some-string--4654052?day=2018-10-17" | sed "s/^.*--\([0-9][0-9]*\)?.*/\1/g"

 Output:  4654052
```

It works by creating a backreference for the number with 1 or more digits right after the `--`, and right before the `?` sign.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, you can use use this regex:

```
/[-]{2}([0-9]+)/
```

It Works by matching 2 `hyphen` characters followed by a Group of any `number` one or more times. It creates a `array` with matches, where captured Groups can be accessed by index.

To access the Group (which conatains the numbers you want), you can do this:

```
var text = 'here-is-some-string--4654052?day=2018-10-17';
var matches= text.match(/[-]{2}([0-9]+)/);
if (matches && matches.length > 1)
{
    var number = matches[1];
}
```